# Attempted to delete invisible tuple + Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pg

I have system where we perform large number of inserts and updates query(something upsert as well)

I see occasionally error on my logs that states ..

```
PG::ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: ERROR:  attempted to delete invisible tuple
 INSERT INTO call_records(plain_crn,efd,acd,slt,slr,ror,raw_processing_data,parsed_json,timestamp,active,created_at,updated_at) VALUES (9873,2016030233,'R',0,0,'PKC01','\x02000086000181f9000101007 ... ')
```

What I fail to understand even when no (delete) query is performed (the above error appear on insert clause) yet the error was thrown.

I have been googling around this issue but no conclusive evidence of why this happen.

### Version of Postgres.

```
database=# select version();
                                                   version                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.5.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Any Clue ??

Comment: Any triggers on that table that would do a delete?

Comment: @PeterEisentraut nope.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I've stumbled upon the same error message, and I can't seem to find any documented solution or what might have caused it.

Comment: Take a look at this bug reported here https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CACOLnRXL-EZ2wwdxq3%3DmrTL5BL21wLu5Z_KUHuMJCcVU1kPf5A%40mail.gmail.com
It probably has to do with the json you are inserting. Load one of your backups to a later version of postgres and see if you are experiencing the same situation on the insert.